# How to force a "statement has no effect" warning on overloaded==

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In the following example:

```
class Test

{
public:
    Test(int _value) { value = _value; };
    const bool operator==(int _value) const { return value == _value; };
private:
    int value;
};

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    a == 1;

    Test b(1);
    b == 1;

    return 0;
}
```

compilation gives the following:

```
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -o test test.cc
a.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cc:13:7: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     a == 1;
     ^
```

This is good as it has warned that I have made an error and mistyped == for =

But the same is true for my Test class. How can I mark up the class or the definition of the operator== to get the compiler to warn me with another "statement has no effect" for the line "b == 1" ?

Comment: [clang warns you about both](https://godbolt.org/g/DxXSW1) :)

Comment: In general, there isn't a way to force this.   In C++17, marking the operator as `[[nodiscard]]` encourages but does not force the compiler to complain.    Beyond that, this sort of thing is a quality of implementation concern - the compiler vendor decides what warnings they support.   So the only solution is to find a compiler that CAN issue such a warning and, since such warnings are often disabled by default, find the configuration option (e.g. command line option) to enable the feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++17, you can mark the operator overload as [`[[nodiscard]]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes):

```
[[nodiscard]] bool operator==(int _value) const { return value == _value; }
```

This will encourage the compiler to produce a warning if the return value is unused.

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LKwvuPxEknwFm98t)

---

From cppreference:

> `[[nodiscard]]`
>
> Appears in a function declaration, enumeration declaration, or class declaration. If a function declared nodiscard or a function returning an enumeration or class declared nodiscard by value is called from a discarded-value expression other than a cast to void, the compiler is encouraged to issue a warning.

Comment: @Rakete1111's comment is supported by the link in this answer: "[...] the compiler is encouraged to issue a warning." Encouraged != required.

Comment: If I add [[nodiscard]] as suggested, it seems to ignore the definitition of the overload and I get:
    test.cc:18:11: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘Test’ and ‘int’)
     if (b == 1)
           ^

Comment: I am using Ubuntu/xenial c++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: @DaveLawrence update your compiler. `[[nodiscard]]` is a C++17 feature. Make sure C++17 is enabled and your compiler supports it.

Comment: unfortunately not possible given our development environment. I guess there isn't going to be a pre C++17 way of doing this.